# Javascript cycling the background color of multiple divs individually

Tags: javascript, css, colors

I have a webpage consisting of 6 boxes, divs, which represent the current status of different systems by traffic light colors - red, amber or green.

I want to be able to cycle through these colors individually for each div so each system can have a different status.

Psuedocode for boxes

```
<div id="system1">System Name</div>
<div id="system2">System Name</div>
<div id="system3">Systen Name</div>
```

and so forth.

The background color is declared red by CSS on page load for all systems and then I want to be able to click each div individually to cycle through to amber then green then back to red to select the most appropriate.

I am struggling with Javascript to get this to work. I was trying to use

```
document.getElementById(elem).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

in an If statement to see what color it is currently and change accordingly but Javascript returns the rgb value. When I tried, for example,

```
document.getElementById(elem).style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(255,231,51)')
```

it doesn't match it even though it should.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try using hex instead of color names like "red"

Comment: Or you could try using an alert to know what type of data is being returned, to change your if accordingly

Comment: They were example codes, I have tried with hex and using an alert. The alert showed the rgb value but when I tried to compare - even when a match - it didn't accept it as a match.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you use class,

```
<style type="text/css">
    .red {background-color:red;}
    .amber {background-color:yellow;}
    .green {background-color:green;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function changeColor(e) {
    var c = e.className;
    e.className = (c == 'red') ? 'amber' : 
                  (c == 'amber') ? 'green' : 
                  (c == 'green') ? 'red' : ''; 
}

</script>
<div class="red" id="system1" onclick="changeColor(this)">System Name</div>
<div class="green" id="system2" onclick="changeColor(this)">System Name</div>
<div class="amber" id="system3" onclick="changeColor(this)">Systen Name</div>

​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/N39Tn/1)

Comment: Thank you, this is definitely what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Browsers translate differently how the colors look when you give them colours like "red".
Also I think your approach is wrong.
I'd use classes that maintain all information.

```
ACommonSystem = function(linkto) 
    {
    this.domobject = linkto;
    // 0 = off, 1 = on, 2 = crashed, 3 = destroyed
    this.state = 0;
    this.errors = null;
    }
ACommonSystem.prototype.turnOn = function()
    {
    if(this.state < 2)
        {
        this.state = 1;
        this.domobject.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
    }
ACommonSystem.prototype.turnOff = function()
    {
    this.state = 0;
    this.domobject.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
ACommonSystem.prototype.crash = function()
    {
    this.state = 2;
    this.domobject.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    this.errors = "I've been kicked";
    }
ACommonSystem.prototype.die = function()
    {
    this.state = 3;
    this.domobject.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    this.errors = "i've burned out";
    }

mysystem1 = ACommonSystem(document.getElementById('system1'));
mysystem1.turnOn();
window.setTimeout(3000,function(){mysystem1.crash();})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately whilst I am sure you put a lot of effort into this I am very new to javascript and this has just confused the hell out of me!

Comment: @GregBains, at least take the time to learn it then!  [S.O. is for _"professional and enthusiast programmers"_](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), so you should not have asked the question if you weren't going to understand the answers.

Comment: I have a basic understanding of javascript and an intermediate understanding of PHP and HTML. I also regularly use other programming languages but am just starting with Javascript. Just because I am new does not mean I am not enthusiastic with programming. I am trying to learn and have been able to understand the other answers which have been posted here. Unfortunately your answer is a lot more complicated than the other answers and that is why I struggled with it. That said I will try to understand it to help my learning.

Comment: Well, what you are doing is very inefficient if you don't learn OOP(object oriented programming)
it's one of the great powers of the C style languages that you can make objects and interact with those so you create "standard" access points which can differentiate.
I suggest you read a tutorial on the following subjects:
Css, javascript object oriented programming, html dom objects and their selectors, prototyping and experimenting.
You need to have a love for programming otherwise you won't keep at it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have not mentioned as tag as Jquery but for your reference I have done this.

If you are willing to go for Jquery, you can do this way:-

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/BD7me/)**

### HTML:

```
<div class="system">System Name</div>
<div class="system">System Name</div>
<div class="system">Systen Name</div>
```

### JQuery:

```
$('.system').click(function() {
    switch ($('div.system').index(this))
    {
        case 0: 
                $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
                break;
        case 1: 
                $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
                break;
        case 2: 
                $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
                break;
    }
});​
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, I don't think is exactly what I want however it has spurred me into looking more into jQuery